# java Filter IllegalStateException or endless loop for fedlet on JBoss 7

Tags: jboss7.x, single-sign-on, servlet-filters, illegalstateexception

I am stuck on a servlet filter problem and am hoping someone can help me.
What I have is a servlet filter (it's a SSO Fedlet) that I'm running on JBoss 7.1.1

This is a simple "Hello World" application that I am just trying to test to get the SSO to work before hitting index.jsp which contains simply "Hello World".

In my doFilter method I go into a handleSSO call, and then upon returning, it calls chain.doFilter(req,res);

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)    throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;


    handleSSO(request, response); //logs in user etc..
     chain.doFilter(req, res);

}
private void handleSSO(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    //login code here where the initiateAuthnRequest occurs for the IdP
    //if successful then do this:
    response.sendRedirect(getRedirectURL(request)); //this is /HelloWorld/
}
```

So what's happening is after sendRedirect is called, it goes back into doFilter and calls the chain.doFilter.
I am then getting an IllegalStateException.
Poking around I read that you can't do both a sendRedirect and a chain.doFilter.
So then I put some logic around the chain.doFilter and only call it if a redirect hasn't occured.
However when this happens I get an endless loop in the doFilter.  As if it is re-authenticating over and over...

So then I thought that my web.xml needs tweeking.  This is what it looks like:

```
<filter>
<filter-name>SamlFilter</filter-name>
     <filter-class>com.gsk.servlet.filters.SAMLFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>SamlFilter</filter-name>
     <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
 </filter-mapping>
```

So my thought is that because the url pattern is /* it will keep on trying to authenticate.
To test this I changed the url-pattern to /HelloWorld/.
However when I do that, I never get into the filter code and the index.jsp page displays.

I am stuck as to what the solution might be.
If anyone has any ideas, that would be great. 
And FWIW, all this code worked fine on Jboss 5, so I don't know if it's a JBoss issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should redirect or call the filterchain:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

    if(needsRedirect(request)){
        handleSSO(request, response); //logs in user etc..
    }else{
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }
}
```